# Change n.d. intext

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex to create a bibliography as follows:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true
]{biblatex}
```

I have the following exemplary entries in my bib file:

```
@online{wikipedia_link_General,
    author = {Everybody},
    title = {Wikipedia!},
    year = {n.d.},
    url = {https://www.wikipedia.org/},
    urldate = {2018-01-31}
}

@online{wikipedia_link_ITA,
    author = {Everybody},
    title = {Wikipedia!},
    year = {n.d.},
    url = {https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale},
    urldate = {2018-01-31}
}
```

Now the resulting output looks like this:

In text:

> Everybody (n.d.(a)) ... and Everybody (n.d.(b)).

Reference list:

> Everybody (n.d.[a]) ..., Everybody (n.d.[b]) ...

Is there any way to change the look? I would like to have [a] and [b] also intext. The default seems not consistent. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: I wrote an answer below with what I'm pretty sure should be the answer, but there is no way of knowing with absolute certainty if it will work if we don't get to see a short example document that reproduces the output you are asking about. In future questions please consider adding a short example document that reproduces the output with as little excess code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Some questions can only be answered with such an MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add parentheses around the citation manually: Use the appropriate command `\autocite` (possibly with `autocite=inline,`, which may or may not be the default already) or `\parencite` for parenthetical citations and `\textcite` for textual Author (Year) citations.

`biblatex`'s parenthesis tracker can only get nested parentheses right if the parentheses are produced by `biblatex`.

Unrelated to the underlying issue, but ideally you should not have to say `year = {n.d.},`. You can get the same result by removing `urldate` from the `labeldate` resolution as shown below (the default `labeldate` setting can be found [in `biblatex.def`, ll. 1341-1348 in v3.14](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1341-L1348)).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
  backend=biber, 
  giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{wikipedia_link_General,
  author  = {Everybody},
  title   = {Wikipedia!},
  url     = {https://www.wikipedia.org/},
  urldate = {2018-01-31},
}
@online{wikipedia_link_ITA,
  author  = {Everybody},
  title   = {Wikipedia!},
  url     = {https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale},
  urldate = {2018-01-31},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
lorem \autocite{wikipedia_link_General}
ipsum \textcite{wikipedia_link_ITA}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: lorem (Everybody n.d.[a]) ipsum Everybody (n.d.[b])]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Just one question remains: If I remove `year` from `DeclareLabeldate` as you suggested, how will the entries be sorted in the reference list? I mean based on what? Normally the year is deciding, and then the athors' surnames as far as I know. But without the year?

Comment: @EtoAls I don't recommend you remove `year`. I removed `urldate`. The default sorting scheme for `authoryear` is `nyt`, which sorts by name, year and title (and finally volume if available), so the title would be tried next. Since the `title` is the same the entries are indistinguishable for the sorting template, then `biblatex` falls back to the order in the `.bib` file as a last resort (but this fortunately does not happen very often). (But the situation would be the same if you didn't change `\DeclareLabeldate` and even if you added the explicit `year = {n.d.},`s)

Comment: Ah interesting, thank you for making that clear. Now I have changed the title of the links. That's why in my document [b] comes before [a]. Mind if I ask if the sorting on the title (in case of `@online` entries only) can be removed somehow? It can happen that in the text `b` occurs before `a` just because of the title when you reference slight variations of the same website multiple times. That seems odd to the reader I assume if you start with let's say `d`, then comes `c`, `b`, `a` only because of the title.

Comment: @EtoAls Well, if you have a clear scheme behind assigning these numbers, your readers will probably not mind. But it is possible to remove the title and only sort by name-year-cite order - the code required to do that, however, won't fit into the comments, so I suggest you ask a new question (with a small example document). (I'll be off now, but I will have a look at it tomorrow.)

Comment: Ok will do, thank you.